# AngularJS with Bootstrap: Suppress redirect when clicking a modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, routes, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router

I have a "Contact" link in my Navbar set to open a form as a modal when clicked. This is using Bootstrap. Recently I decided to add some AngularJS routing to my site and it works great for all links except this one. My route config looks like this:

```
asApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route otherwise
            .otherwise({
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            });

    });
```

Since I don't have a dedicated page for the contact form (it's meant to open as a modal), I haven't added any specific routing for "/contact" in the above code which is why clicking that link triggers the "route otherwise" block and redirects opens up the home page. Is there any way to suppress this routing only for the "Contact" link? I want it to stay on the page that was open when the link was clicked and the modal opened. Not sure if I have been coherent enough so please feel free to ask me if you are lost.

In case it helps, here's the modal snippet along with some other relevant HTML parts:

```
/* Navbar snippet */
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-controller="HeaderController">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/about')}"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

/* Main body snippet */
<div id="main"><div ng-view></div></div>

/* Modal snippet */
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    /* Contact form code here... */
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks a ton for your attention and help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `data-target` to not mess with the angular routes (url after #)

```
<a href data-target="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! What a simple solution...worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: what to when i open modal through ng-click to suppress redirect to home page??

Answer (score 0):

There is a great module `ui.bootstrap` by angularUI team for using angular with bootstrap:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

It has a `$modal` service to handle opening views as a modal.

However if you don't want to use that, you can try the following:

The most simple solution will be not to have the `contact` as a anchor tag.

Use a `div` with `ng-click` instead.

i.e., in place of `<li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal">Contact</a></li>`

use `<li><div class="contact-modal" ng-click="functionThatOpensModal()">Contact</div></li>`

And you can style this specific div to look same as the other links.

Hope this helps